# Why is the first assassin in the city not available for missions?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

In Mediterranean Defense, I have three assassins assigned to one city, but when I try to send them on missions it turns out that the first one is unavailable. I can't even move the cursor over him and there's no indication of *why*.

Is the first assassin assigned to a city always unavailable? Is there any reason for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one is the den master and cannot be sent on missions, you can only send the other assassins assigned to the city (up to 4)

Comment: This isn't exactly accurate - they're not den masters in the sense that your dens in Constantinople have masters.  You CAN switch them out, you just have to leave at least one assassin in the city.